# Trying to customize default markup for exposed filter

Tags: theming, views

Would it be possible customize the markup of an exposed filter? Currently I'm displaying the exposed filter for a view using a block. My complaint is the bloated markup Drupal generates.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That markup is pretty standard; one wrapping div under the form for valid HTML (`<input>` can't be a direct descendant of `<form>` for example), a wrapper for each form element so AJAX functionality works, a label and an input element. You're not going to be able to remove anything without either breaking the potential for AJAX functionality to work, or breaking HTML validity

Comment: @Clive So I'm guessing the only way to do this to build your own custom exposed filter?

Comment: Nah, they're just form elements at the end of the day. Use a `hook_form_alter`, add an `#element_theme` to the elements you want to control the markup for, and add `#theme` to `$form` if you want to control the wrapping output

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, so basically with `hook_form_alter` I could modify the markup of any exposed filter that I have setup in my views? https://imgur.com/a/7GgDNun

Comment: Yes I think so. Unless you're using better exposed filters or something similar, I don't think there's any special core theming for exposed filters. As far as I know they're standard form elements which means you can theme them as such

Comment: @Clive I've tried `better exposed filter` but it only seems to be working on `8.3`. Currently on `8.5.4` at the moment

Comment: Module version numbers don't follow core (except for major) - 8.3.x for BEF just means it's the 3rd release of that module. I have it working fine on 8.5.4

Comment: @Clive Ok will try again, hmm I'll try downloading and installing using `drush`